# register_shutdown_function exit with custom code

Tags: php

How can i exit with a custom code after register_shutdown_function() is called? I have this:

```
function shutdown()
{
   $a = error_get_last();

   if ($a != null) 
   {
      exit(3);
   }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Even though I specify exit code 3 it always exits with 255.

Comment: Probably because `$a == null` so `exit` is not called.

Comment: @AbraCadaver does the same when I comment the if statement and only use exit(3).

Comment: What PHP version?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Version 7.4.15

Comment: May be platform specific or something https://3v4l.org/tjKEk

Comment: @AbraCadaver Now I know that the code isn't the problem. I'll try it on a different platform. Thanks!